# Mocking using MOQ and generic types

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Method to unit test: GetUserInfo

Following is the class containing the method:

```
public class AccountService : IAccountService
{
    IUnitOfWork _UnitOfWork;

    public AccountService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public UserInfo GetUserInfo(string userName, string password)
    {
        var userInfo = new UserInfo();
        userInfo.UserType = UserType.Invalid;

   // Statement of interest
   var portalUser = _UnitOfWork.Repository<DvaPortalUser>().Query().Filter(t => t.Email == userName && t.Password == password).Get().FirstOrDefault();

        //....Rest of the code is not included for clarity
    }
}
```

The interface to mock IUnitOfWork:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void Dispose();
    void Save();
    void Dispose(bool disposing);
    IRepository<T> Repository<T>() where T : class;
}
```

Repository Implementation:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{

    public virtual RepositoryQuery<TEntity> Query()
    {
        var repositoryGetFluentHelper = new RepositoryQuery<TEntity>(this);

        return repositoryGetFluentHelper;
    }

  internal IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>,
            IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        List<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>>
            includeProperties = null,
        int? page = null,
        int? pageSize = null)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = DbSet;

        if (includeProperties != null)
            includeProperties.ForEach(i => query.Include(i));

        if (filter != null)
            query = query.Where(filter);

        if (orderBy != null)
            query = orderBy(query);

        if (page != null && pageSize != null)
            query = query
                .Skip((page.Value - 1)*pageSize.Value)
                .Take(pageSize.Value);


        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

RepositoryQuery Implementation:

```
public sealed class RepositoryQuery<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly List<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>> _includeProperties;

    private readonly Repository<TEntity> _repository;
    private Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> _filter;
    private Func<IQueryable<TEntity>,
        IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> _orderByQuerable;
    private int? _page;
    private int? _pageSize;

    public RepositoryQuery(Repository<TEntity> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _includeProperties = new List<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>>();
    }

    public RepositoryQuery<TEntity> Filter(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter)
    {
        _filter = filter;
        return this;
    }


    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Get()
    {
        return _repository.Get(
            _filter,
            _orderByQuerable, _includeProperties, _page, _pageSize);
    }
}
```

Unit Test Method:

```
 [TestMethod]
 public void AccountService_GetUserInfo_SuccessfulLogin()
 {
    var  _UnitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    _AccountService = new AccountService(_UnitOfWork.Object);

    _UnitOfWork.Setup(a =>  a.Repository<T>())).Returns(??); //How do I setup this statement?
    _UnitOfWork.VerifyAll();
 }
```

Question: How do I setup mock call for the statement _UnitOfWork.Repository()?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how your `IRepository<T>` is implemented, but i gues your `Query` method returns a `IEnumerable<T>` or a list.

```
internal interface IRepository<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> Query();
}

// your mock
_UnitOfWork.Setup(a =>  a.Repository<DvaPortalUser>())).Returns(() => new MyTestRepository());
```

#### 1. Solution

Define a explicit implemtation of you repository.

```
// your implementation
public class MyTestRepository : IRepository<DvaPortalUser>
{
    public IEnumerable<DvaPortalUser> Query()
    {
       // return some test users (mocks)
       return new List<DvaPortalUser> {new DvaPortalUser(), new DvaPortalUser()};
    }
}
```

#### 2. Solution (thanks to Yuliam Chandra)

Define a mock instead of the implemtation

```
var repository = new Mock<IRepository<DvaPortalUser>>(); 
// return some test users (mocks)
repository.Setup(a => a.Query()).Returns(new[] { new DvaPortalUser() });
_UnitOfWork.Setup(a =>  a.Repository<DvaPortalUser>()).Returns(repository.Object);
```

What you choose depends on your solution.

Comment: Why don't create a mock too for the repository instead of the stub?

Comment: Because your mock needs to know the types to handle. Generics <T> cannot be used i guess.

Comment: how about something like `var rep = new Mock<IRepository<DvaPortalUser>>();` then `rep.Setup(a => a.Query()).Returns(new[] { new DvaPortalUser() });` and then followed by `_UnitOfWork.Setup(a =>  a.Repository<DvaPortalUser>())).Returns(rep.Object);` disclaimer: code in browser, not tested yet

Comment: ah ok, now i understand your comment. Right, thats another way. I will add that to the answer. Thanks!